# How to use python-telegram-bot to send messages to a telegram channel

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I created a telegram bot and added it to my telegram channel. Now, I want to use it to send messages to my channel, when something is happening in my python program. For example, I have a python program that checks the weather every 15 secs, and when there's a change in the weather, I want my bot to send the new weather information to my telegram channel.

So my question is, how can I do it? I'm stuck because python-telegram-bot requires a message from the user to get triggered, or a scheduled orders, while I can't schedule it because I don't know when the weather will change.

Comment: You can get the weather, then store it in another temp variable. Then You can use a if condition, to check if weather info in that temp variable is same or not. If it isn't, send the message via bot, and update the temp variable. You can use a while True loop, with time.sleep(interval) to run the check weather function after set interval

Comment: yes, that's what I wanted to do, but the problem is with python-telegram-bot library. It doesn't allow you to send a message without a user request or schedule a message in a known time

Answer (score 11):

The easiest method to do this is to use the request method.
Telegram provides a cool API to send messages with your bot, you need to do that with a link for example :

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<yourbottoken>/sendMessage?chat_id=<yourchatid>&text=Hello World!
```

What this does is that it will send the Hello World message to a certain chat id.
If you don't know how to get a chat id, you need to DM your bot and you can use this link :

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<yourbottoken>/getUpdates
```

In the page, there will be quite a lot of JSON data, you need to use Control + F and search for your telegram username without the @ and search for the chat id

If you want to do this in a python code, you need to use the `requests` module.

```
import requests
requests.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot<yourbottoken>/sendMessage?chat_id=<yourchatid>&text=Hello World!')
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about telegram API. that makes my life much easier. where can I find all the API request method links? And one more thing, how can I send the message in a formatted string and let's say with \n in python? Thanks!

Comment: Hey! you can read more about it in [Telegram Bot API Manual](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)
You can use markdown formatting, it's [Here!](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options)

Comment: It didn't work for me

Comment: @SAM what did not work?

Comment: @Quebeh using requests.post didn't work.

Comment: @SAM did it give any error? What statuscode?

Comment: no it didn't give any error

Comment: @SAM did it just not send to the target?

Comment: Thanks a lot the problem was from ISP.